# PHP Determine host safely and reliable

Tags: php, host, server-variables

For my script, which relies on the host url, I need to determine the host and whether it's connection over HTTP protocol or HTTPS protocol.

for instance, if I connect to http://example.com, I would like to retrieve **http** and **example.com**

I can of course use the `$_SERVER` variables. However, I have read on the internet that they are easily changeable by the client. Therefore, they 'could' break my script. So, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, etc become unreliable I guess?

Is there any better option to tackle this issue instead of checking both $_SERVER variables for the same value, which is still unreliable?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make a config.php file where you define some constants that you need and then just include it anywhere you need them. Or maybe i misunderstood, but i think this is what you want

Comment: Well, the script will run on clients web servers. It's like a widget they can install and run from their servers connecting to my server (like an API), so no unfortunately this is not an option. Or I misunderstood you completely